# Why does cargo test show me trace! logs when I specify RUST_LOG=debug?

Tags: testing, logging, rust, rust-cargo

Why does `cargo test` show me `trace!` logs when I specify `RUST_LOG=debug`?

I'm using `SimpleLogger` as a test backend, initialized like that (`init_logger` is called at the beginning of each test function):

```rust
static INIT_LOGGER: Once = Once::new();

pub fn init_logger() {
    INIT_LOGGER.call_once(|| {
        SimpleLogger::new().init().unwrap();
    });
}
```

I run the tests with:

```bash
RUST_LOG=debug cargo test
```

And I see all log messages, `INFO`, `DEBUG`...

I'd like to see only the `DEBUG` messages.

Also, I'd like to see only the messages from my own crate, not from its dependencies, is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SimpleLogger` by default does not react to environment variables.

Use the [`.env()`](https://docs.rs/simple_logger/latest/simple_logger/struct.SimpleLogger.html#method.env) method to enable that behaviour:

```rust
use std::sync::Once;

use simple_logger::SimpleLogger;

static INIT_LOGGER: Once = Once::new();
pub fn init_logger() {
    INIT_LOGGER.call_once(|| {
        SimpleLogger::new().env().init().unwrap();
    });
}

fn main() {
    init_logger();
    log::error!("error");
    log::warn!("warn");
    log::info!("info");
    log::debug!("debug");
    log::trace!("trace");
}
```

```
> RUST_LOG=debug cargo run
2022-07-09T14:49:19.733Z ERROR [streamer] error
2022-07-09T14:49:19.733Z WARN [streamer] warn
2022-07-09T14:49:19.733Z INFO [streamer] info
2022-07-09T14:49:19.733Z DEBUG [streamer] debug

> RUST_LOG=info cargo run
2022-07-09T14:49:25.022Z ERROR [streamer] error
2022-07-09T14:49:25.022Z WARN [streamer] warn
2022-07-09T14:49:25.022Z INFO [streamer] info
```

Or use the much more popular [`EnvLogger`](https://crates.io/crates/env_logger) instead.

With `EnvLogger` you can do exactly what you were asking for; you can enable different log levels for different dependencies. [Here is a more detailed description](https://docs.rs/env_logger/0.9.0/env_logger/#enabling-logging) of what can be achieved with `EnvLogger`.

```rust
use std::sync::Once;

static INIT_LOGGER: Once = Once::new();
pub fn init_logger() {
    INIT_LOGGER.call_once(|| {
        env_logger::init();
    });
}

fn main() {
    init_logger();
    log::error!("error");
    log::warn!("warn");
    log::info!("info");
    log::debug!("debug");
    log::trace!("trace");
}
```

```
> RUST_LOG=debug cargo run
[2022-07-09T14:52:42Z ERROR streamer] error
[2022-07-09T14:52:42Z WARN  streamer] warn
[2022-07-09T14:52:42Z INFO  streamer] info
[2022-07-09T14:52:42Z DEBUG streamer] debug

> RUST_LOG=info cargo run
[2022-07-09T14:52:46Z ERROR streamer] error
[2022-07-09T14:52:46Z WARN  streamer] warn
[2022-07-09T14:52:46Z INFO  streamer] info
```

Comment: You seem like you know more about logging within Rust tests than most people. If you wouldn't mind taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/73293801/470749 I'd appreciate it. Thanks!